# Is it possible to define the title in an R Markdown file as a header?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I want to use tabs in my markdown document. I can apply the .tabset class attribute to my header, that's no issue. However, I would like to apply it to my title. Let's say I have the following code:

````
---
title: 'Header 1'
author: "Homer Simpson"
date: "4/26/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Header 1 {.tabset}

## Header 2
````

So header 1 appears twice. But I would like to start with Header 2 and not repeat header 1 again. How How would I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding to give a name to the tabset solves you issue:

````
---
title: 'Header 1'
author: "Homer Simpson"
date: "4/26/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# {.tabset}

## Header 2

## Header 3
````

Or similarly avoiding the document `title`:

````
---
author: "Homer Simpson"
date: "4/26/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Header 1 {.tabset}

## Header 2

## Header 3
````

Comment: @ GGamba Thanks for your quick reply. Seem rather obvious ;-)